# Passing "int" as argument in macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

This has been bugging me for some time, I came across this while solving some objective type questions in C.

```
#define SWAP(a,b,c) c t;t=a;a=b;b=t;

int main() {
    int x=10,y=20;
    SWAP(x,y,int);     
}
```

The code gives the correct answer:
[Working code](http://ideone.com/Bsfn9I)

In C are we  supposed to pass just a data type as an argument.This supposedly works here but I want to know how.Also two more questions related to this:

1. If I want to swap using pointers, will it work
2. Will this work if SWAP is defined as a function instead of a macro.

Comment: You can even use symbols in macros:  `#define OP(a,b,op) a op b` and then `if ( OP(3, 5, <) ) printf("lol\n");` . So long as you don't use `,`, `)` or cause a digraph or trigraph of course :)

Comment: @Tushar what I understood by your second question is "You want to write generalized SWAP() function that will swap the values of any data type". and It is possible with template.

Comment: but you cant pass data type as an argument. :(

Answer (score 7):

Macros are pre-processed before compilation and you can virtually write anything in macros that would be replaced. In function arguments, you can not pass data types as arguments.

Side note:

```
#define SWAP(a,b,c) do { c t;t=a;a=b;b=t; } while(0)
```

is a safer macro implementation than the one mentioned by you. Moreover name t is quite common. If either of the argument name is t, this won't work as expected, so better choose some rare name. Capital letters are usually preferred in macro definition.

for ex: `#define SWAP(a,b,c) do { c MACRO_TEMP_;MACRO_TEMP_=a;a=b;b=MACRO_TEMP_; } while(0)`

`SWAP(x,y,int);` Becomes `c t;t=a;a=b;b=t;` where all occurances of c are replaced with int, a with x and b with y. Resulting in: `ìnt t; t = x; x = y; y = t;`

To understand the macros better, you can see the pre-processed output of your code. Output on my computer:

```
$ cat q26727935.c
#define SWAP(a,b,c) c t;t=a;a=b;b=t;

int main() {
    int x=10,y=20;
    SWAP(x,y,int);     
}

$ gcc -E q26727935.c 
# 1 "q26727935.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "q26727935.c"


int main() {
    int x=10,y=20;
    int t;t=x;x=y;y=t;;
}
$
```

1. Macro is replacement at pre-processor stage, so [swap will work even with pointers](http://ideone.com/z8EXv7), although this is superfluous.
2. In function you can not pass data type as arguments, so it won't work.

Comment: Why the do while bit - that is not required - the braces are though

Comment: @EdHeal Braces will make the variable local. do while will make this macro usable under blocks (do/if/while etc) without the requirement of `{}`

Comment: .. But you example has braces?

Comment: @EdHeal [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. No.

First of all, you have to know that when you are using macros, the argument will be *replaced* as they are. So, if you call SWAP(a, b, int*), it will be replace with

```
int* t;t=a;a=b;b=t;
```

and then the code will be compiled.

But when you're using functions, that won't happen and you're unable to pass data type as an argument to a function.